# Last <li> not in place with others

Tags: html, css

This is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4fsehxg0/1/) example. My `ul.nav` is `910px` and i have 7 `li.nav` inside it. I set their width to `130px` each but the last one is out of place. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try increasing the min/max width of ul.nav

```
 ul.nav {
            width: 90%;
            min-width: 1000px;
            max-width: 1000px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
```

```css
        nav.nav {
          width: 100%;
          min-width: 980px;
          max-width: 1024px;
          height: 40px;
          padding: 0;
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
        ul.nav {
          width: 90%;
          min-width: 1000px;
          max-width: 1000px;
          margin: 0 auto;
        }
        li.nav,
        a.nav {
          width: 130px;
          display: inline-block;
        }
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="nav">
    <a href="#" class="nav">
      <li class="nav">Home</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="nav">
      <li class="nav">Home</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="nav">
      <li class="nav">Home</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="nav">
      <li class="nav">Home</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="nav">
      <li class="nav">Home</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="nav">
      <li class="nav">Home</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="nav">
      <li class="nav">Home</li>
    </a>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I tried to increase the min-width to 940px, everything is in place but its not quite in the center of the page. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yep, After i add margin-left and margin-right to auto. The code work perfectly. And also i found another way to create a nav bar like this which is more simple. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

set an exact width on your last nav and it works:

```
 <a href="#" class="nav" style="width:40px">
     <li class="nav">Home</li>
 </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to reduce nav length

```
    li.nav, a.nav {
        width: 110px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

I reduced 130 to 110

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below css

```
    nav.nav {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 980px;
        max-width: 1024px;
        height: 40px;
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    ul.nav {
        width: 90%;
        min-width: 910px;
        max-width: 910px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    li.nav, a.nav {
        width: 130px;
        float: left;
    }
    ul.nav:after {
        content:"";
        clear:both;
        display:block;
    }
    li.nav {
       list-style-type:none;
       padding: 12px 0;
       box-sizing:border-box;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. instead `<a href="#" class="nav"><li class="nav">Home</li></a>`

   use - `<li class="nav"><a href="#" class="nav">Home</a></li>`
2. maybe use `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` for `ul.nav`?

```css
nav.nav {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 980px;
    max-width: 1024px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
ul.nav {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 980px;
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;       
    text-align: center;    
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
ul.nav > li {
    width: 130px;       
}
ul.nav > li a{
    display: block;        
}
ul.nav > li a:hover{
    background: #ccc;        
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```